# How to change text font in graph generated by hydroplot?

Tags: r, fonts, plot, boxplot

I'm trying change the text font of a graph generated by function `hydroplot()` in `hydroTSM`, I tried various ways but no success, `hydroplot()` is a function that generates 3 plots a time: `serie`, `boxplot` and `histogram`. Sometimes I can change just one of these. See the example below:

```
require(hydroTSM)

data(OcaEnOnaQts)

hydroplot(OcaEnOnaQts, FUN=mean, ylab= "Q", var.unit = "m3/s")
```

Also I can´t change the title of graphs because the function paste a text before the my `main`. Must I change the source code of function to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the authors provided no way to really customize those plots. I'm afraid you will have to change the source. To make it worse, they seem to create those titles pretty far down in the chain. Some are set in `hydroTSM:::.hydroplotts` and various other un-exported functions.

Comment: I was wondering if there a way to change the font of the chart that will leave the device, generally in R, there?

Comment: and other, as I live in Brazil also have to translate some function where titles are not customizable.

Comment: @Artur_Indio Do you mean you want to use a specific system font? R really only let's you choose between "serif", "sans" and "mono". I think you can set the `family=` parameter to one of those.

Comment: set where? in function? don't works...i wondering something like that set.font.R.out in own console